# Populate a form before opening in MS Access/VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form in MS Access 2013.  I'd like to print most, but not all, of the values on the parent form (excluding some text fields, buttons, etc).  My initial approach is to create a child form with only the fields I'd like to be printed.  Upon clicking on a "print" button, I'd like to populate the fields on the child form with the corresponding data from the parent form, open the form, and print it.

1. is this the correct approach to achieve what i'm trying to do?
2. if so, can i create an instance of the form object, populate it, and open it (much as i would do in Java, which is the base of my coding knowledge).  what would that code look like?

Thanks,

jeff

Comment: I think we could do with more background to this. Can you define each source of data? Is it a continuous subform? Can you be more precise rather than say 'I'd like to print most...'. Do you want to print from the parent or subform? Could you set up a query for excatly what you want then send that to a spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1):

In Access controls (textboxes, lables, checkboxes, etc) have a property called "display when".  You can set controls to be displayed "Screen Only" so they won't appear when you click print.

Comment: sorry for the unclear description, but this response was the easiest way to solve my problem.  thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

While we could do with some more of an explanation it sounds like you want to print information to do with a record you are looking at.  You could make a form that looks how you want it to print, then on click of a button from your main form you can open the record you are viewing in the print form.  Then print from there.